# How to use arithmetical operations i YML file?

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I'm using SpringBoot.

In previous projects I was using application.property file, and content looks look this:

```
seconds.timeOut=10
interval.milliseconds.cleaner=#{${seconds.timeOut}*2*1000}
interval.seconds.cleanerOffset=#{${seconds.timeOut}*3}
```

result was correct cleaner=20000 and cleanerOffset=30

In new project I switch to application.yml file. Have same configuration:

```
      seconds:
        timeOut: 10
      interval:
        milliseconds:
           cleaner: ${seconds.timeOut}*2*1000
      interval:
        seconds:
          cleanerOffset: ${seconds.timeOut}*3
```

but result is string cleaner = "10*2*1000"
Of course I have exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'cleaningWorker': Invalid fixedDelayString value "10*2*1000" - cannot parse into long
```

I can't found any workaround could you help me?

Comment: did you already try `#{${seconds.timeOut}*2*1000}` as the value in the YAML file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use SpringBoot SpEL in YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62812548/421195)

Comment: yes I try #{${seconds.timeOut}*2*1000} and this is not working!

Comment: @blurfus 
Thanks that is exactly what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all.

this solution for me:

```
      seconds:
        timeOut: 10
      interval:
        milliseconds:
           cleaner: '#{${seconds.timeOut}*2*1000}'
      interval:
        seconds:
          cleanerOffset: '#{${seconds.timeOut}*3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(( ${seconds.timeOut} * 2000seconds ))
```

If this didn't work please refer to [this](https://esm-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yaml.html#arithmetic-operations), this will help.

Comment: I think there is syntax error in your solution.  `2000seconds` does not seem correct.  Also, OP wanted to have these calculations in the YAML file

Comment: Syntax of 2000seconds is correct as similar worked fine in my YAML file. You can also use days, years, and months.